# CSS breakage on page reload running on Spring Boot

Tags: java, html, css, angular, primavera

I have an angular application packaged in Spring, in the resorce/static folder, in spring there is a    configuration class to always look at the html, it happens that when reloading the page there is a css    break presenting a quick html and returning to the source page.
this is my targeting class:

```
  `  @Override
     public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
      registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
            .resourceChain(true)
            .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                @Override
                protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws       IOException {
                    Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                    return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ?  requestedResource
                            : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
                }
            });
   }`
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KU85a.jpg)

I tried making a configuration that authorizes to control access to different parts of your   Spring  Boot  application, allowing public access to some static resources, while requiring authentication for  other   parts of the application. Authentication is performed using HTTP basic authentication. But it  didn't work.

```
          ` protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/assets/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/files/**", "/other-files/**", "/resources/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .httpBasic();
     }`
```

Comment: What does the "Network" section of your browser developer tools say about the requests being made?